# How to merge multiple text files by column?

Tags: bash, shell

I have 20 files in my directory, now like to merge the columns of the files by column 1. Examples of files are given below:

Note: column 1 (#rname) is not sorted but has a similar number of rows over the input files. Column 2 can be ignored from the input files when generating the output file.

File1:

```
#rname  startpos    endpos  numreads    covbases    coverage    meandepth   meanbaseq   meanmapq
CFLAU10s2|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37904   6   375 0.989341    0.0157503   35.6    31
CFLAU10s4|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37174   2   222 0.597192    0.00812396  35.7    45
CFLAU10s5|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37080   2   70  0.188781    0.00377562  35.7    28
CFLAU10s6|kraken:taxid|33189    1   36175   4   145 0.400829    0.00801659  36.9    25.5
CFLAU10s8|kraken:taxid|33189    1   35457   4   155 0.437149    0.00874298  37  25.5
CFLAU10s9|kraken:taxid|33189    1   34752   6   111 0.319406    0.0191644   36.2    26
CFLAU10s13|kraken:taxid|33189   1   32255   2   156 0.483646    0.00917687  35.2    20
CFLAU10s14|kraken:taxid|33189   1   31915   4   63  0.197399    0.00695598  36.7    26.5
```

file2:

```
#rname  startpos    endpos  numreads    covbases    coverage    meandepth   meanbaseq   meanmapq
CFLAU10s2|kraken:taxid|33189    1   26432   8   318 1.20309 0.0361683   35.9    35
CFLAU10s4|kraken:taxid|33189    1   26105   2   91  0.348592    0.00697184  35  37
CFLAU10s5|kraken:taxid|33189    1   25631   4   122 0.475986    0.00951972  35.7    26
CFLAU10s6|kraken:taxid|33189    1   25014   2   64  0.255857    0.00511713  34.7    28
CFLAU10s8|kraken:taxid|33189    1   24803   522 10847   43.7326 2.22175 36.3    32.8
CFLAU10s9|kraken:taxid|33189    1   24139   2   59  0.244418    0.00488835  37  43
CFLAU10s13|kraken:taxid|33189   1   23391   24  1215    5.19431 0.109273    36.1    35.5
CFLAU10s14|kraken:taxid|33189   1   22963   12  318 1.38484 0.0531289   36.8    15.3
```

expected output_file:

```
#rname  file1_endpos    file1_numreads  file1_covbases  file1_coverage  file1_meandepth file1_meanbaseq file1_meanmapq  file2_endpos    file2_numreads  file2_covbases  file2_coverage  file2_meandepth file2_meanbaseq file2_meanmapq
CFLAU10s2|kraken:taxid|33189    37904   6   375 0.989341    0.0157503   35.6    31  26432   8   318 1.20309 0.0361683   35.9    35
CFLAU10s4|kraken:taxid|33189    37174   2   222 0.597192    0.00812396  35.7    45  26105   2   91  0.348592    0.00697184  35  37
CFLAU10s5|kraken:taxid|33189    37080   2   70  0.188781    0.00377562  35.7    28  25631   4   122 0.475986    0.00951972  35.7    26
CFLAU10s6|kraken:taxid|33189    36175   4   145 0.400829    0.00801659  36.9    25.5    25014   2   64  0.255857    0.00511713  34.7    28
CFLAU10s8|kraken:taxid|33189    35457   4   155 0.437149    0.00874298  37  25.5    24803   522 10847   43.7326 2.22175 36.3    32.8
CFLAU10s9|kraken:taxid|33189    34752   6   111 0.319406    0.0191644   36.2    26  24139   2   59  0.244418    0.00488835  37  43
CFLAU10s13|kraken:taxid|33189   32255   2   156 0.483646    0.00917687  35.2    20  23391   24  1215    5.19431 0.109273    36.1    35.5
CFLAU10s14|kraken:taxid|33189   31915   4   63  0.197399    0.00695598  36.7    26.5    22963   12  318 1.38484 0.0531289   36.8    15.3
```

Comment: In your example, both input files have exactly the same join keys in exactly the same order. Is that always the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{array[$1]=$3FS$4FS$5FS$6FS$7FS$8; next} { print $0,array[$1]}' file2 file1
#rname  startpos    endpos  numreads    covbases    coverage    meandepth   meanbaseq   meanmapq endpos numreads covbases coverage meandepth meanbaseq
CFLAU10s2|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37904   6   375 0.989341    0.0157503   35.6    31 26432 8 318 1.20309 0.0361683 35.9
CFLAU10s4|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37174   2   222 0.597192    0.00812396  35.7    45 26105 2 91 0.348592 0.00697184 35
CFLAU10s5|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37080   2   70  0.188781    0.00377562  35.7    28 25631 4 122 0.475986 0.00951972 35.7
CFLAU10s6|kraken:taxid|33189    1   36175   4   145 0.400829    0.00801659  36.9    25.5 25014 2 64 0.255857 0.00511713 34.7
CFLAU10s8|kraken:taxid|33189    1   35457   4   155 0.437149    0.00874298  37  25.5 24803 522 10847 43.7326 2.22175 36.3
CFLAU10s9|kraken:taxid|33189    1   34752   6   111 0.319406    0.0191644   36.2    26 24139 2 59 0.244418 0.00488835 37
CFLAU10s13|kraken:taxid|33189   1   32255   2   156 0.483646    0.00917687  35.2    20 23391 24 1215 5.19431 0.109273 36.1
CFLAU10s14|kraken:taxid|33189   1   31915   4   63  0.197399    0.00695598  36.7    26.5 22963 12 318 1.38484 0.0531289 36.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a single command to do this, but you can do it more programmatically like this and get the task done.

For this first run a

```
IFS="
"

kram@00w87:/tmp$ for each in `grep -v "#" file1`;do v=`grep \`echo "$each"|cut -d"|" -f1\` file2`;echo "$each $v";done
CFLAU10s2|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37904   6   375 0.989341    0.0157503   35.6    31 CFLAU10s2|kraken:taxid|33189    1   26432   8   318 1.20309 0.0361683   35.9    35
CFLAU10s4|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37174   2   222 0.597192    0.00812396  35.7    45 CFLAU10s4|kraken:taxid|33189    1   26105   2   91  0.348592    0.00697184  35  37
CFLAU10s5|kraken:taxid|33189    1   37080   2   70  0.188781    0.00377562  35.7    28 CFLAU10s5|kraken:taxid|33189    1   25631   4   122 0.475986    0.00951972  35.7    26
CFLAU10s6|kraken:taxid|33189    1   36175   4   145 0.400829    0.00801659  36.9    25.5 CFLAU10s6|kraken:taxid|33189    1   25014   2   64  0.255857    0.00511713  34.7    28
CFLAU10s8|kraken:taxid|33189    1   35457   4   155 0.437149    0.00874298  37  25.5 CFLAU10s8|kraken:taxid|33189    1   24803   522 10847   43.7326 2.22175 36.3    32.8
CFLAU10s9|kraken:taxid|33189    1   34752   6   111 0.319406    0.0191644   36.2    26 CFLAU10s9|kraken:taxid|33189    1   24139   2   59  0.244418    0.00488835  37  43
CFLAU10s13|kraken:taxid|33189   1   32255   2   156 0.483646    0.00917687  35.2    20 CFLAU10s13|kraken:taxid|33189   1   23391   24  1215    5.19431 0.109273    36.1    35.5
CFLAU10s14|kraken:taxid|33189   1   31915   4   63  0.197399    0.00695598  36.7    26.5 CFLAU10s14|kraken:taxid|33189   1   22963   12  318 1.38484 0.0531289   36.8    15.3
```

then you just need to add the header and that's it!

This command will merge it all, then you need to drop columns using cut for example, or even awk. I think awk will do it quicker, this is just a preview.

```
for each in `grep -v "#" file1`;do v=`grep \`echo "$each"|cut -d"|" -f1\` file2`;echo "$each $v";done | awk '{print $1" "$8" "$9}'
CFLAU10s2|kraken:taxid|33189 35.6 31
CFLAU10s4|kraken:taxid|33189 35.7 45
CFLAU10s5|kraken:taxid|33189 35.7 28
CFLAU10s6|kraken:taxid|33189 36.9 25.5
CFLAU10s8|kraken:taxid|33189 37 25.5
CFLAU10s9|kraken:taxid|33189 36.2 26
CFLAU10s13|kraken:taxid|33189 35.2 20
CFLAU10s14|kraken:taxid|33189 36.7 26.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the [column](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column) command, and tell it to use tabs to separate columns

```
paste file1 file2 | column -s $'\t' -t
```